# One item (button) is always smaller in iOS UIStackView

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uistackview

Using Xcode 7.2 [using swift but that shouldn't matter for this] ... I have put two buttons, 'Done' and 'Add', into a UIStackView as such:

[image]

But at runtime the 'Add' button is always smaller as:

[image]

I have tried every combination of fill and spacing on the StackView, etc. I have tried setting widths and heights but the 'Add' button is always smaller. I have the same problem in another UIStackView (also horizontal) where the Add button is first.

The two buttons shown have the same natural pixel size and are multi-sized. For example here is the setting for 'Add':

[image]

I tried deleting it from Xcode and adding it back. Is there some factor that I am missing? This is driving me nuts.

*One hint that might help is that I think that when I first added it with this name, it actually was smaller, but since then I have deleted it and re-included it in the project. Perhaps there is some 'memory' there that I can't find?*

Comment: ah the joys of auto-layout... have you checked the constraints?

Comment: Tried cleaning your project? Deleting derived data?

Answer (score 0):

Ack, thanks so much for the answers and comments. But the problem was that the '@2x' Add image was misscaled. Fixing that fixed the problem; only took me days to find it as I guess I checked and rechecked the 1x and 3x sizes but never the 2x one. Sorry to waste your collective time.

I am still not very comfortable with all the layout settings and have 6 storyboards in the app that have around 60 layout warnings, but am getting there.